# CardView layout_width="match_parent" does not match parent RecyclerView width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a fragment with contains a RecyclerView with layout_width="match_parent":

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" />
```

The item in the RecyclerView is a CardView also with layout_width="match_parent":

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I inflate the item view as below:

```
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_listitem, null, true);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
```

But when I run the app, the CardView is rendered as wrap_content as shown below:

[image: CardsBug]

Note that this was run on emulator, not a real device.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug?

Comment: When inflating the CardView, are you supplying the parent view with a true parameter?

Comment: Hi @NiekHaarman, please see the edit. I added the inflating code. And yes I have passed the true parameter.

Answer (score 306, accepted):

The docs for `inflate`:

> Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource. Throws
>   InflateException if there is an error.
>
> Parameters
>   **resource**  ID for an XML layout resource to load (e.g.,
>   R.layout.main_page) root
>   **view** to be the parent of the
>   generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an
>   object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the
>   returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)
>   **attachToRoot**  Whether
>   the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter? If
>   false, root is only used to create the correct subclass of
>   LayoutParams for the root view in the XML. Returns The root View of
>   the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied and attachToRoot is true,
>   this is root; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file.

It is important here to *not* supply true, but *do* supply the parent:

```
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_listitem, parent, false);
```

Supplying the `parent` View lets the inflater know what layoutparams to use. Supplying the `false` parameter tells it to *not* attach it to the parent just yet. That is what the `RecyclerView` will do for you.

Comment: Could you explain why supplying true would cause it to be `wrap_content` in the first place?

Comment: The solution didn't work for me because the ListView's `layout_width` was `wrap_content`. Its weird because this shouldn't affect the list view! So my understanding is that when you provide false as a parameter to the layoutinflater, the ListView adds the list items to the ListView with layout parameters matching the ListView itself! :0

Comment: could you post a little more code, because I think I'm doing the same, but actually it isn't working

Comment: I am inflating how you suggestion and match_parent is not working for me.

Comment: I think the correct understanding is that when you set attachToRoot to false, you need to supply an object with defined LayoutParams value. That object is not necessarily the parent. "...simply an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)..." But I don't understand why inflater cannot read the LayoutParams that defined in the CardView but need another object parameter to inform it?

Comment: If I use custom view, how to deal with it? I mean `ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(...) { View v = new MyItemView(parent.getContext); return new ViewHolder(v); }`

Comment: @nhaarman can you please help me to solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066346/cardview-gridlayout-with-recyclerview-is-not-fit-for-all-screen-sizes-in-andro

Comment: @Nikson No I cannot.

Answer (score 78):

Use RelativeLayout as the immediate parent to CardView.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" ... >
    <CardView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" ... >
    </CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes this seemed to work for me as well.  I was using LinearLayout and the suggestion above didn't work since I was already doing exactly that (ie not attaching to root, but providing a parent).  You have to do both RelativeLayout + not attaching parent, but providing one.

Comment: It works for me, but I don't know why do this can solve the problem.
Does anyone can explain why?

Comment: it's been ages, android x is in production, still the bug is not fixed !

Comment: the easiest way.

Comment: I had a similar problem and this worked for me to correct the width of my card view but I am having a similar problem with the height? Can you suggest me something for that as well?

Comment: Work like charm

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me,

```
 View viewHolder= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item, null, false);
 viewHolder.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 return new ViewOffersHolder(viewHolder);
```

Answer (score 6):

The way I did it is:

```
View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_cardview, null, true);
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            int width = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(width, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

**Explanation:**
In your onCreateViewHolde once you get card view, get the screen width and then set the layout param accordingly for card view.

Comment: please improve this slightly. It basically says "Try this"

Comment: Added Explanation. Please check and if need any further help, comment here.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be fixed in `'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'`

See: [RecyclerView wrap_content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867709/recyclerview-wrap-content) for further discussions.

Answer (score 4):

Default implementation force the use of **wrap_content** in the default layout manager :

```
  @Override
public LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    return new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}
```

All you have to do is to override this method in your LayoutManager like this :

```
  @Override
public LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    return new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply set new layout params

```
view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
));
```

Comment: I found doing this in onBindViewHolder() useful when using a custom view class that inherits from ConstraintLayout.

Comment: It is not a good answer because the margin that is been set to the layout will be affected.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, ***null***, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  card_view:contentPadding with a negative value

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    card_view:contentPadding="-4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

It worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Wrap `CardView` in a Layout that has width:`match_parent`