# layout_margin in CardView is not working properly

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-cardview

I am playing with the new **CardView**, but the margins don't seem to be applying.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFA"
card_view:layout_margind="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"/>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

By the way, I'm using it in a **Fragment** that is in a **ViewPager**. The card extends the entire width of the screen (**match_parent**) even though I am using `android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"` and `android:layout_marginRight="18dp"` on the **CardView**.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ViewPager.LayoutParams does not extend ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams

It's that simple.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.LayoutParams.html

Answer (score 37):

If you use RecyclerView to add CardView, android:layout_margin should be sufficient.

But using ListView to add CardView, you might do this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp">
       (other layout ...)
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

But it is usually not the optimal one.

Comment: Seems like an ugly hack but worked for me.  Will do this until I convert to `RecylerView`.

Comment: AbsListView.LayoutParams does not extend ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.LayoutParams.html  Thus, margins will not work for immediate child Views.
RecyclerView.LayoutParams does extend MLP, though, thankfully.

Answer (score 27):

I had the same issues before, I found answer in here...
[CardView layout_width="match_parent" does not match parent RecyclerView width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503760/cardview-layout-width-match-parent-does-not-match-parent-recyclerview-width)

At the time of inflating the CardView xml inside your ViewPager, pass the ViewGroup in it. this will allow inflater to know which layout parameters to refer.

To inflate the layout file use something like below:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_list_item, viewGroup,false);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Where would I use that code?  I am using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: at the time you are inflating view, either in fragment or adapter.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Never saw this in any RecyclerView/CardView tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your card view inside a layout in order to properly show margins, especially if the card view is shown as an item in a recycler view.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is not efficient, but it gets the work done. This should not have been downvoted!

Comment: yes worked for me as well & my cardview is not under any list of recyclerview

Answer (score -1):

Set **app:cardPreventCornerOverlap** property to **false** in cardView

`<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
...
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
...`

Comment: there is no such attribute