# recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Just implemented `RecyclerView` in my code, replacing `ListView`.

Everything works fine. The data is displayed.

But error messages are being logged:

```
15:25:53.476 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

15:25:53.655 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

for the following code:

```
ArtistArrayAdapter adapter = new ArtistArrayAdapter(this, artists);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

As you can see I have attached an adapter for `RecyclerView`.
So why do I keep getting this error?

I have read other questions related to the same problem but none of them help.

Comment: is artists empty ? what happens you switch setAdapter and setLayoutManager?

Comment: You have to use a RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: @BlackBelt nothing different happens when i switch setAdapter and setLayoutManager (i see all the artists and the error message in logcat as well)

and as for is artists empty?, I'm calling this code from retrofit's success after it finishes downloading all the data. So i don't think artists is empty (as i can see all the artists!)

Comment: @FreeFlyer94 ArtistArrayAdapter is a class extending RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: You might be seeing it if you are not initializing recyclerview as soon as it is attached to the window.

Comment: @yigit I'm waiting for retrofit to download data and after it's finished the given code runs!

Comment: ok then it makes sense because recycler view is laid out before u have data thus it prints the error.

Comment: @yigit but after successful download I see the data...
so can the error be ignored?
or how do i fix it?

Comment: you can ignore it. or if u want to get rid of it, set an empty adapter when you initialize RecyclerView.

Comment: How serious is this error? Can this be ignored? Anyways I use setAdapter(null) to avoid the error.

Comment: Reference this article https://makecodesimpleandeasy.blogspot.com/p/erecyclerview-no-adapter-attached.html

Comment: i am puzzled by the answers suggesting binding the adapter in onCreate. at that point, the view hasn't been created, so findViewById isn't available. nor does Android Studio allow me to put setContentView at that point. it seems i MUST wait until onViewCreated to bind the adapter. what am I missing here?

Comment: i kept same thing but order was wrong in my case, i was keeping setAdapter lastly making cause

Answer (score 287, accepted):

Can you make sure that you are calling these statements from the "main" thread outside of a delayed asynchronous callback (for example inside the `onCreate()` method).
As soon as I call the same statements from a "delayed" method. In my case a `ResultCallback`, I get the same message.

In my `Fragment`, calling the code below from inside a `ResultCallback` method produces the same message. After moving the code to the `onConnected()` method within my app, the message was gone...

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
list.setLayoutManager(llm);
list.setAdapter( adapter );
```

Comment: But I need to download the data first then display!

Comment: Just set an empty adapter first, update it as soon as you have the data (this is what works for me).

Comment: That's what yigit suggested!

Comment: More or less, in my app I'm working with the Google Drive API. I perform the initialization within the onConnected method using an empty adapter, when I receive the ResultCallback I'm adding the data into the adapter.

Comment: @equitharn You should set a empty adapter first,and then the data is downloaded,call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(),that is worked for me.

Comment: This solution isn't helping me. In fact no solution in this thread is helping me. Can someone please look into my case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225232/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout-data-not-showing)

Comment: One liner:   list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)

Comment: I had that code in a function that was never colled from onViewCreated

Comment: This solution works for me. I forgot 'llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);'. After adding this, the skipping layout error is gone. Thanks

Comment: @DomonLee How can I do that? Can you look at my question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/68559418/13935956

Comment: @Peter How can I do that? Can you look at my question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/68559418/13935956

Comment: How much different is the Kotlin version of this code?

Answer (score 53):

I was getting the same two error messages until I fixed two things in my code:

(1) By default, when you implement methods in the `RecyclerView.Adapter` it generates:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

Make sure you update your code so it says:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return artists.size();
}
```

Obviously if you have zero items in your items then you will get zero things displayed on the screen.

(2) I was not doing this as shown in the top answer: [CardView layout_width="match_parent" does not match parent RecyclerView width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503760/cardview-layout-width-match-parent-does-not-match-parent-recyclerview-width)

```
//correct
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_listitem, parent, false);

//incorrect (what I had)
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.card_listitem,null);
```

(3) EDIT: BONUS:
Also make sure you set up your `RecyclerView` like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

NOT like this:

```
<view
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I have seen some tutorials using the latter method. While it works I think it generates this error too.

Comment: my getItemCount() looks like this `public int getItemCount() {
        return artists == null ? 0 : artists.size();
    }`
and the LayoutInflater `View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_listitem, parent, false); `

Comment: this works for me: @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return artists.size();
    }

Comment: Oh God. That moment when you come back to SO, and see an answer that you already upvoted, and realize that you were doing the same stupid thing. Thank again @Micro.

Answer (score 25):

I have the same situation with you, display is ok, but error appear in the locat.
That's my solution:
(1) Initialize the RecyclerView & bind adapter ON CREATE()

```
RecyclerView mRecycler = (RecyclerView) this.findViewById(R.id.yourid);
mRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

(2) call notifyDataStateChanged when you get the data

```
adapter.notifyDataStateChanged();
```

In the recyclerView's source code, there is other thread to check the state of data.

```
public RecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.mObserver = new RecyclerView.RecyclerViewDataObserver(null);
    this.mRecycler = new RecyclerView.Recycler();
    this.mUpdateChildViewsRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(RecyclerView.this.mFirstLayoutComplete) {
                if(RecyclerView.this.mDataSetHasChangedAfterLayout) {
                    TraceCompat.beginSection("RV FullInvalidate");
                    RecyclerView.this.dispatchLayout();
                    TraceCompat.endSection();
                } else if(RecyclerView.this.mAdapterHelper.hasPendingUpdates()) {
                    TraceCompat.beginSection("RV PartialInvalidate");
                    RecyclerView.this.eatRequestLayout();
                    RecyclerView.this.mAdapterHelper.preProcess();
                    if(!RecyclerView.this.mLayoutRequestEaten) {
                        RecyclerView.this.rebindUpdatedViewHolders();
                    }

                    RecyclerView.this.resumeRequestLayout(true);
                    TraceCompat.endSection();
                }

            }
        }
    };
```

In the dispatchLayout(), we can find there is the error in it:

```
void dispatchLayout() {
    if(this.mAdapter == null) {
        Log.e("RecyclerView", "No adapter attached; skipping layout");
    } else if(this.mLayout == null) {
        Log.e("RecyclerView", "No layout manager attached; skipping layout");
    } else {
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but in my version I cannot use "this.findViewById()" in onCreate to define the RecyclerView. it is simple forbidden by Android Studio (cannot resolve). nor does it allow me to use setContentView. this answer is old so I assume this is a version issue. i am forced to wait to set the adapter until onViewCreated, when i can use findViewById to define the RecyclerView. I must be missing something!

Answer (score 16):

i have this problem , a few time problem is **recycleView put in ScrollView** object

After checking implementation, the reason appears to be the following. If RecyclerView gets put into a ScrollView, then during measure step its height is unspecified (because ScrollView allows any height) and, as a result, gets equal to minimum height (as per implementation) which is apparently zero.

You have couple of options for fixing this:

1. Set a certain height to RecyclerView
2. Set ScrollView.fillViewport to true
3. Or keep RecyclerView outside of ScrollView. In my opinion, this is the best option by far. If RecyclerView height is not limited - which is the case when it's put into ScrollView - then all Adapter's views have enough place vertically and get created all at once. There is no view recycling anymore which kinda breaks the purpose of RecyclerView .

(Can be followed for `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` as well)

Comment: setting ScrollView.fillViewport to true solved my problem, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 12):

1) Create [ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) that does nothing :)

```
// SampleHolder.java
public class SampleHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public SampleHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

---

2) Again create [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) that does nothing :)

```
// SampleRecycler.java
public class SampleRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SampleHolder> {
    @Override
    public SampleHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SampleHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

3) Now when your real recycler is not ready just use the sample one like below.

```
RecyclerView myRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_id);
myRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
myRecycler.setAdapter(new SampleRecycler());
```

---

This is not best solution though but it works! Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi , please i have the same error and i don't know where  i should check if the recycler is not ready tto passe an empty adapter) and where i can check if the  recycler is ready(to pass the adapter with data)

Comment: This is great, here's a drag'n drop style gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bcf027945f08f40601090c55d6048e21

Answer (score 10):

It happens when you are not setting the adapter during the creation phase:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    ....
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ....
}
```

Just move setting the adapter into onCreate with an empty data and when you have the data call:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: make sure you  set data in customadapter constructor within onCreate method

Answer (score 6):

Check if you have missed to call  this method in your adapter

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin we had this weird illogical issue.

This didn't work:

```
 mBinding.serviceProviderCertificates.apply {
            adapter = adapter
            layoutManager =  LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        }
```

While this worked:

```
mBinding.serviceProviderCertificates.adapter = adapter
mBinding.serviceProviderCertificates.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
```

Once I get more after work hours, I will share more insights.

Comment: I'm shocked, that's actual issue I had. Very strange indeed.

Comment: Wow, weird. Even weirder is that it works if you replace `apply` with `let` , `also` or `run`.

Comment: Yes its working for me!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you set the layout manager for your RecyclerView by:

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
```

Instead of `LinearLayoutManager`, you can use [other](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html) layout managers too.

Answer (score 4):

```
ArtistArrayAdapter adapter = new ArtistArrayAdapter(this, artists);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Just replace above code with this and it should work. What you did wrong is you called setAdapter(adapter) before calling layout manager.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error I fixed it doing this if you are waiting for data like me using retrofit or something like that

Put before Oncreate

```
private ArtistArrayAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
```

Put them in your Oncreate

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
 adapter = new ArtistArrayAdapter( artists , R.layout.list_item ,getApplicationContext());
 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When you receive data put

```
adapter = new ArtistArrayAdapter( artists , R.layout.list_item ,getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now go in your ArtistArrayAdapter class and do this what it will do is if your array is empty or is null it will make GetItemCount return 0 if not it will make it the size of artists array

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    int a ;

    if(artists != null && !artists.isEmpty()) {

        a = artists.size();
    }
    else {

        a = 0;

     }

   return a;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who use the `RecyclerView` within a **fragment** and inflate it from other views: when inflating the whole fragment view, make sure that you bind the `RecyclerView` to its root view.

I was connecting and doing everything for the adapter correctly, but I never did the binding. 
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48389399/5450198) by *@Prateek Agarwal* has it all for me, but here is more elaboration.

**Kotlin**

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val rootView =  inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false)
    recyclerView = rootView?.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_id)
    // rest of my stuff
    recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView?.layoutManager = viewManager
    recyclerView?.adapter = viewAdapter
    // return the root view
    return rootView
}
```

**Java**

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout,container,false);
    recyclerview= rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_id);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my layout xml file, the bottom line with layoutManager was missing. The error disappeared after I added it.

```
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_chat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

These Lines must be in `OnCreate`:

```
mmAdapter = new Adapter(msgList);
mrecyclerView.setAdapter(mmAdapter);
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the actual inflated layout is different from that which is being referred by you while finding the recyclerView. By default when you create the fragment, the onCreateView method appears as follows:
`return inflater.inflate(R.layout.<related layout>,container.false);`

Instead of that, separately create the view and use that to refer to recyclerView
`View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.<related layout>,container.false);
recyclerview=view.findViewById(R.id.<recyclerView ID>);
return view;`

Comment: I spent hours on this. This is the response that worked in my case. 
binding.recyclerView was not the correct reference.
Instead I got the RecyclerView like this:
recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.m_recyler_view)

Answer (score 2):

First initialize the adapter

```
public void initializeComments(){
    comments = new ArrayList<>();

    comments_myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.comments_recycler);
    comments_mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(myContext);
    comments_myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(comments_mLayoutManager);

    updateComments();
    getCommentsData();

}

public void updateComments(){

    comments_mAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(comments, myContext);
    comments_myRecyclerView.setAdapter(comments_mAdapter);
}
```

When ever there is a change in the dataset set, just call the updateComments method.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error, and I tried to fix for a while until I found the solution.

I made a private method buildRecyclerView, and I called it twice, first on onCreateView and then after my callback (in which I fetch data from an API). This is my method buildRecyclerView in my Fragment:

```
private void buildRecyclerView(View v) {
        mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_loan);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new LoanAdapter(mExampleList);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Besides, I have to modify the method get-Item-Count in my adapter, because On on-Create-View the list is null and it through an error. So, my get-Item-Count is the following:

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        try {
            return mLoanList.size();
        } catch (Exception ex){return 0;}

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I just added layout manager to the recyclerview and got fixed.
In the recyclerview in your XML file just add `app:layoutManager`

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/recyclerViewData"
     .
     .
     android:orientation="vertical"
     app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
     .
     ./>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this error. You just need to add layout manager 
and add the empty adapter.

Like this code:

```
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(...//your layout manager);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerView.Adapter() {
            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return 0;
            }
        });
//other code's 
// and for change you can use if(mrecyclerview.getadapter != speacialadapter){
//replice your adapter
//}
```

Comment: i do it for beginner users

Answer (score 1):

This is really a simple error you are getting, there in no need of doing any codes in this.
*This error occurs due to the wrong layout file used by the activity.  By IDE i automatically created a layout v21 of a layout which became a default layout of the activity.*
all codes I did in the old layout file and new one was only having few xml codes, which led to that error.

**Solution: Copy all codes of old layout and paste in layout v 21**

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was setting the adapter inside `onLocationChanged()` callback AND debugging in the emulator. Since it didn't detected a location change it never fired. When I set them manually in the Extended controls of the emulator it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to `RecyclerView`

```
app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

Example:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you're getting still error while using **ViewBinding**, make sure you're using the binding to return the inflated view ie

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return fragmentBinding.getRoot();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my situation it was a forgotten component which locates in ViewHolder class but it wasn't located in layout file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and realized I was setting both the **LayoutManage**r and **adapter** after retrieving the data from my source instead of setting the two in the **onCreate** method.

```
salesAdapter = new SalesAdapter(this,ordersList);
        salesView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        salesView.setAdapter(salesAdapter);
```

Then notified the adapter on data change

```
               //get the Orders
                Orders orders;
                JSONArray ordersArray = jObj.getJSONArray("orders");
                    for (int i = 0; i < ordersArray.length() ; i++) {
                        JSONObject orderItem = ordersArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        //populate the Order model

                        orders = new Orders(
                                orderItem.getString("order_id"),
                                orderItem.getString("customer"),
                                orderItem.getString("date_added"),
                                orderItem.getString("total"));
                        ordersList.add(i,orders);
                        salesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because you are not adding any `LayoutManager` for your `RecyclerView`.

Another reason is because you are calling this code in a NonUIThread. Make sure to call this call in the UIThread.

The solution is only you have to add a `LayoutManager` for the `RecyclerView` before you `setAdapter` in the UI Thread.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
```

Comment: If you need to delay setting LayoutManager you should do this from your callback method:
           recyclerView.post(() -> {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemOffsetDecoration(itemGap));
            });

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting the initialized empty list and adapter at the bottom and calling notifyDataSetChanged when results are fetched.

```
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerviewItems.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    someAdapter = new SomeAdapter(getContext(),feedList);
    recyclerviewItems.setAdapter(someAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I lost 16 minutes of my life with this issue, so I'll just admit to this incredibly embarrassing mistake that I was making- I'm using Butterknife and I bind the view in onCreateView in this fragment.

It took a long time to figure out why I had no layoutmanager - but obviously the views are injected so they won't actually be null, so the the recycler will never be null .. whoops!

```
@BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
public View onCreateView(......) {
    View v = ...;
    ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
    setUpRecycler()
 }

public void setUpRecycler(Data data)
   if (recyclerView == null) {
 /*very silly because this will never happen*/
       LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
       //more setup
       //...
    }
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new XAdapter(data));
}
```

If you are getting an issue like this trace your view and use something like `uiautomatorviewer`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened cause i embedded a RecyclerView in a LinearLayout.

I previously had a layout file only containing one root RecyclerView as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_products"

    android:name="Products.ProductsFragment"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context=".Products.ProductsFragment"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"/>
```

I believe the problem is within the 3 lines separated. Anyway, I think its a simple problem, ill be working on it tomorrow; thought i should write what i found before forgetting about this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Adding yet another answer since I came across this thread googling the error. I was trying to initialize a `PreferenceFragmentCompat` but I forgot to inflate the preference XML in `onCreatePreferences` like this:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, null)
    }

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        // Missing this line here:
        //   setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings, rootKey)
    }
}
```

The error was a mystery until I realized that `PreferenceFragmentCompat` must be using a `RecyclerView` internally.

Answer (score 0):

// It happens when you are not setting the adapter during the creation phase: call notifyDataSetChanged() when api response is getting **Its Working**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);


        magazineAdapter = new MagazineAdapter(getContext(), null, this );
        newClipRecyclerView.setAdapter(magazineAdapter);
        magazineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

       APICall();
}

public void APICall() {
    if(Response.isSuccessfull()){
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   }
}
Just move setting the adapter into onCreate with an empty data and when you have the data call:

mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same issue, I did every thing correct excepted in xml file:

- step first 1: initialize recyclerview & List & Adaptor:

  ```
  RecyclerView recyclerview;
  List<ModelName> list;
  ProvideBidAdaptor adaptor;
  ```
- step 2: bind it in onCreate-

  ```
  recyclerview = findByViewId(R.id.providerBidRV);
  recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
  recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
  list = new ArrayList<>();
  ```
- step 3: Where you getting response or list - add list- (i am getting from response)>

  ```
  responseList.addAll(response.getResponse());
  adaptor = new ProvideBidAdaptor(this, responseList);
  binding.detailsRV.setAdapter(adaptor);
  ```

Here is my xml file where i implement `RecyclerView`:
I was forget orientation in `LinearLayout`, after this correction- `RecyclerView` attached.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".activities.Bidding.ProvideBid">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/app_toolbar"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/providerBidRV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Here is Adaptor:

```
    public class ProvideBidAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProvideBidAdaptor.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<Response> responseList;
    DateTime dateTimeInstance = new DateTime();

    public ProvideBidAdaptor(Context context, List<Response> responseList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.responseList = responseList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.geo_presence_item_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Response detailsResponse = responseList.get(position);
        if (!detailsResponse.getUserId().isEmpty()) {

            holder.day.setText(detailsResponse.getDay());
            holder.locationType.setText(detailsResponse.getLocationType());

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return responseList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView date,locationType;
        CardView provideBidCV;
        LinearLayout dayLLayout,locationTypeLLayout;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_value);
            day = itemView.findViewById(R.id.day_value);
            locationType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.locationType_value);

            locationTypeLLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.locationTypeLLayout);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 override fun onCreateView(...  ): View? 
   {
        val rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, 
        container,false)

        val recycler_menu_list = 
         rootview.findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu_list) as RecyclerView

        recycler_menu_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        val data =  ...

        foodCardAdapter = FoodCardAdapter()

        recycler_menu_list.adapter=foodCardAdapter

        foodCardAdapter.submitList(data)      

       //make sure that the return view is one declared above up and is 
       //not the default 'inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu,         
       //container,false)' created by the ide

        return rootview    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set attachToRoot attribute to false in the inflate() method of your databinding or whatever you're using to display views like so:

inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting this error because I forgot to attach the layout manager in my XML layout file.

It was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_to_do"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:listitem="@layout/item_generic"
    tools:context=".ToDoActivity">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

By adding the attribute `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"` (and the corresponding namespace `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` which was auto-added by Android Studio) my XML layout file became:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_to_do"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"

    tools:listitem="@layout/item_generic"
    tools:context=".ToDoActivity">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and the error disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

In your `RecyclerView` adapter class, for example `MyRecyclerViewAdapter`, make a constructor with the following params.

```
MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); // <-- This is the line most people include me miss
    this.mData = data;
}
```

`mData` is the data that you'll pass to the adapter. It is optional if you have no data to be passed.
`mInflater` is the `LayoutInflater` object that you have created and you use in the `OnCreateViewHolder` function of the adapter.

After this, you attach the adapter in the MainActivity or wherever you want to on the main/UI thread properly like

```
MyRecyclerViewAdapter recyclerAdapter;
OurDataStuff mData;

    ....
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Like this:

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, mData); //this, is the context. mData is the data you want to pass if you have any
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    }
   ....
```

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me.

1. Do this if you are using the emulator.

> android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

2. If your cardview xml design is like this,

> android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Replace cardview xml design with android x.
 Must be such;

> androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

3. If your recyclerview xml design is like this,

> android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Replace cardview xml design with android x.
 Must be such;

> androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Comment: Nothing about this answer makes sense

Answer (score -1):

**Just put code inside onCreate() method**

```
/* Like This*/

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(YourActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mAdapter = new YourAdapter(YourModelClassObject);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```