# @EViewGroup as RecycleView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-annotations

As we need use *ItemView_.build(activity)* to inflate item view, we can not pass parent view to *Inflater* and face with the problem of invalid item width, described at
[CardView layout_width="match_parent" does not match parent RecyclerView width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503760/cardview-layout-width-match-parent-does-not-match-parent-recyclerview-width)

Maybe need to add support of *build* method with *View parent* param?

Comment: This is not the problem though. I tried using the parent view to inflate and I still got the same issue with everything being squished to the left. I think it has to do with `CooridnatorLayout`, but that's just a theory