# Set vertical Recyclerview item view to height= match_parent doesn't match the device's height

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to set the height of the first view on my recyclerview to match_parent.
That is, the first view should cover the entire device.
Here's the XML for this first view, note height and width set to match_parent

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:contentPadding="14dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_icon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="IC"
            android:textSize="100sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/temp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="12°"
                android:textColor="@color/normal_text"
                android:textSize="86dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="LIGHT SNOW"
                android:textColor="@color/light_text"
                android:textSize="14dp" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"

        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <com.feresr.rxweather.UI.views.InfoDisplay
            android:id="@+id/humidity"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:ic="&#xf07a;"
            app:sub="Humid." />

        <com.feresr.rxweather.UI.views.InfoDisplay
            android:id="@+id/tempMax"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:ic="&#xf050;"
            app:sub="East" />

        <com.feresr.rxweather.UI.views.InfoDisplay
            android:id="@+id/tempMin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:ic="&#xf079;"
            app:sub="Press." />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <com.feresr.rxweather.UI.views.InfoDisplay
            android:id="@+id/clouds"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:ic="&#xf013;"
            app:sub="Cluds" />

        <com.feresr.rxweather.UI.views.InfoDisplay
            android:id="@+id/precipitation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:ic="&#xf084;"
            app:sub="0.29 mm" />

        <com.feresr.rxweather.UI.views.InfoDisplay
            android:id="@+id/feels_like"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:ic="&#xf055;"
            app:sub="Feels like " />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason, when running this on my device I see the view as wrap content instead. Any kind help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up calculating the height at runtime and setting it to my view dinamically.

```
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int height = size.y;
            currentlyViewHolder.view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height));
```

If anyone know how to do it on XML I can change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the vertical recyclerView doesn't have height is match Parent if you use `WindowManager` and `Point.size`. 
I'll explain how your answer work in this Image:

[image]

To resolve this problem You can use `ViewTreeObserver` like this in Activity's `onCreate`:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = recyclerViewItems.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            recyclerViewItems.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            //get height of RecyclerView's Match Parent
            finalHeight = recyclerViewItems.getMeasuredHeight();           

            LinearLayoutManager itemsLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            itemsLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerViewItems.setLayoutManager(itemsLayoutManager);
            VerticalAdapter verticalAdapter = new VerticalAdapter(DataList<>());
            recyclerViewItems.setAdapter(verticalAdapter);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

whether or not `match_parent` in an XML layout works depends on how it is inflated. So our list item views should be inflated as follows in order to make the `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in the view holder to work:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewholder, recyclerView, false);
```

A couple of important things to note about the code above is that:

- [`LayoutInflater.inflate(resource,root,attachToRoot)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)) is the method used to inflate the list item views.
- a reference to the recycler view was passed as the `root` parameter into the `inflate` method. *This is important because when `match_parent` is encountered for the root node of the inflating XML, it will match the dimensions of the `root` `View`.*
- `false` is passed into the `inflate` method for the `attachToRoot` parameter. *This is important because we don't actually want the `inflater` to attach the inflated view to the`root`... the recycler view will take care of attaching the view to itself.*

This [other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24504126/2898715) is very related.