# RecyclerView items don't fill width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have designed a layout with map fragment and recyclerView. 
Each recyclerView item is cardview (I have specified give the xml layout).

The problem is RecyclerView item doesn't fill screen width. 
[img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz0px.png)

I tried to change layout_width to `fill_parent`, `match_parent` ... but it can't help

Here is the layout **for each item**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/locationItemView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120px"
            android:layout_height="120px"
            android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Location Name"
                android:textColor="#d5c645"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:padding="3dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Location Address"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:padding="3dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDistance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Location Distance"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and the **main_layout**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".Main"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_weight=".6"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/locationList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight=".4"
        android:divider="#FEFFCC"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navdrawer"
    android:layout_width="250px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/white"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Hope anyone can help me. I am stuck with it for 3 days.
Thank you.

====================================
Edit on 19/11/15
I don't thing the problem is my itemView layout because when I change it to GridLayout it still doesn't fill the width.
Here is my CustomAdapter for RecyclerView

```
public class LocationDetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationDetailsViewHolder> {
    Context _context;
    ArrayList<LocationDetails> _data;

    public LocationDetailsAdapter(Context _context, ArrayList<LocationDetails> _object) {
        this._context = _context;
        _data = _object;
    }

    @Override
    public LocationDetailsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View _v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_location,null );
        LocationDetailsViewHolder _viewHolder = new LocationDetailsViewHolder(_v);

        return _viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LocationDetailsViewHolder locationDetailsViewHolder, int i) {
        LocationDetails _location = _data.get(i);
        locationDetailsViewHolder._imgType.setImageResource(R.drawable.repair_img);
        locationDetailsViewHolder._locationName.setText(_location.get_locationName());
        locationDetailsViewHolder._locationAddress.setText(_location.get_locationAddress() + ", " + _location.get_district() + ", " + _location.get_province());
        locationDetailsViewHolder._distance.setText(String.valueOf(_location.get_distance()) + " km");

        locationDetailsViewHolder._locationName.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        locationDetailsViewHolder._imgType.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        locationDetailsViewHolder._locationAddress.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

locationDetailsViewHolder._locationName.setTag(locationDetailsViewHolder);
        locationDetailsViewHolder._imgType.setTag(locationDetailsViewHolder);
        locationDetailsViewHolder._locationAddress.setTag(locationDetailsViewHolder);
}

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != _data ? _data.size() : 0);
    }

    View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LocationDetailsViewHolder _holder = (LocationDetailsViewHolder)v.getTag();
            int _pos = _holder.getPosition();

            int _id = _data.get(_pos).get_id();

            Intent _intent = new Intent(CommonFields._context, ItemView.class);
            _intent.putExtra("LocationID",_id);
            _intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            CommonFields._context.startActivity(_intent);
        }
    };
}
```

and here I get RecylerView in main

```
_locationView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.locationList);
_locationView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
_adapter = new LocationDetailsAdapter(Main.this, CommonFields._locationData);
_locationView.setAdapter(_adapter);
```

Comment: Show your Java code. In particular, the spot where you inflate the itemView layout when creating a `ViewHolder`.

Comment: show a screen shot to how do your item look ?

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503760/cardview-layout-width-match-parent-does-not-match-parent-recyclerview-width

Comment: can you use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`?

Comment: @Arslan I can't attach an image in this post so I have a link to it, you can see in the top "img here"

Comment: @HareshChhelana: tks, but it doesn't help

Comment: @Droidekas: I tried all but nothing changed

Answer (score 62, accepted):

When inflating a `View` from a `LayoutInflater`, you need to pass a parent parameter in order for `layout_*` attributes to be used. That's because these attributes need to create the correct `LayoutParams` class. That means that you can't use `inflate(R.layout.*, null)`, but must instead pass a `ViewGroup` for the second parameter. In most cases, you also want to use the three-parameter version of the method and pass `false` as the third parameter. If this is omitted or `true` then the `View` is immediately added to the parent, which causes problems in places like `onCreateViewHolder()` because the framework is designed to perform this operation later instead. For more details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5027921/2565340).

In your case, you have the line

```
 View _v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_location,null );
```

You should change it to

```
 View _v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_location, viewGroup, false );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and explaination. It work.
It seem to have so many thing I have to learn

Comment: Man you are a life saver! I have been struggling with this small mistake around a week now.

Comment: perfect solution and explanation, saved me bunch of time... thanks dude!

Answer (score 4):

You should create `View` like this

```
@Override
public CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {  
// create a new view
   View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.card_view, viewGroup, false);
// create ViewHolder
   ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
   return viewHolder;
 }
```

Comment: I just create custom adapter for RecyclerView, not for CardView. I just edit my post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer has a different approach, but it works to occupy the entire width of the screen and not break the elements when passing through the recycling view.

```
Adapter adapterBalanceInquiry = new Adapter(getActivity(), list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterBalanceInquiry);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false));
        recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int dx = (recyclerView.getWidth() - recyclerView.getChildAt(0).getWidth());
                    recyclerView.scrollBy(-dx, 0);
                    LinearSnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
                    recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(null);
                    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Improved answer @RussHWolf
If you are using data binding in Adapter than

```
val binding = ViewBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )

return MyViewHolder(binding)
```

finally

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int):
        MyViewHolder{
        val binding = ViewBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return MyViewHolder(binding)
    }
```