# How to set initial layout_width of cards in Recycler View to Match_Parent?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-cardview, recyclerview-layout

I am facing issue with rendering items in recycler view. The problem happens with the items that are initially loaded as you can see in the pic below that layout width doesn't become screen wide(match_parent).

[image]

Now when I scroll, new items do span screen wide.

[image]

And when I scroll up, previous items also become screen wide.

[image]

So it seems that there is some issue with initial loaded cards. Here is the code...

Adapter:

```
class SearchAdapter(searchInp : ArrayList<BusNumbers>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchViewHolder>() {

    var searches : ArrayList<BusNumbers>? = searchInp

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SearchViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        var bus : BusNumbers = searches!!.get(position)
        holder!!.updateUI(bus)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): SearchViewHolder {
        var cardBuses : View = LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context).inflate(R.layout.card_bus_numbers,parent,false)
        return SearchViewHolder(cardBuses)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return searches!!.size
    }
}
```

Holder:

```
class SearchViewHolder(itemView : View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var Title : TextView? = null
    init {
        Title = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.cardSearchText)
    }

    fun updateUI(bus : BusNumbers){
        Title!!.text = bus.Number
    }
}
```

Fragment calling adapter:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_loader, container, false)
    var recyclerview : RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerSearch)
    recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)

    var adapter  = SearchAdapter(BusNumberData.ourInstance.getBusNumbers())
    recyclerview.adapter = adapter

    var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    layoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
    recyclerview.layoutManager = layoutManager

    return view
}
```

Card_Layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="360">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardSearchText"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="320"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="TestText"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="40" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Recycler:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerSearch"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mandarsadye.mandar.ess_user.Fragments.SearchPackage.SearchLoader">

    <include layout="@layout/content_search_recycler"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I already referred these questions but either they don't solve my problem or the mistakes made in these question are not same as mine.

1. [match_parent width does not work in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691150/match-parent-width-does-not-work-in-recyclerview)
2. [CardView layout_width="match_parent" does not match parent RecyclerView width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503760/cardview-layout-width-match-parent-does-not-match-parent-recyclerview-width/24504126)
3. [RecyclerView items don't fill width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772003/recyclerview-items-dont-fill-width)

if someone has any idea how to make initially loaded items screen wide please tell.
Thank you.

Comment: you dint post your top cardView in cardView layout !! (Card_layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer after hours of digging...

Just replace:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textreplaced"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="xyz" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

by:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textreplaced"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="xyz" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Though I don't have any idea why it happened.
So If anyone knows the reasoning he/she may post an answer for this and I will mark that as accepted answer as this one is just workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a **view** between the **TextView** and **Button** and set its width to **match_parent**

Comment: thanks for the reply...but suggestion didn't work in my case