# android full width cardview in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recylcer view and each row contain cardview.I need to show cardview full width even my textview content is less .I tried many ways but no use.

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primaryDarkColor"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:padding="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:text="content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#ff212121"

                />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Even i have set width to match parent but no use.

**Updated**

Recycler view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/List"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Updated :Fixed using following method**

I have fixed my issue using following answer

The docs for inflate:

> Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource. Throws
>   InflateException if there is an error.
>
> Parameters resource ID for an XML layout resource to load (e.g.,
>   R.layout.main_page) root view to be the parent of the generated
>   hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that
>   provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned
>   hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.) attachToRoot Whether the
>   inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter? If false,
>   root is only used to create the correct subclass of LayoutParams for
>   the root view in the XML. Returns The root View of the inflated
>   hierarchy. If root was supplied and attachToRoot is true, this is
>   root; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file.

It is important here to not supply true, but do supply the parent:

```
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_listitem, parent, false);
```

Supplying the parent View lets the inflater know what layoutparams to use. Supplying the false parameter tells it to not attach it to the parent just yet. That is what the RecyclerView will do for you.

This answer helped me to fix my problem

Ref: 
[CardView layout_width="match_parent" does not match parent RecyclerView width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503760/cardview-layout-width-match-parent-does-not-match-parent-recyclerview-width)

Comment: use paddingLeft and paddingRight instead of layout_marginLeft and layout_marginRight in your cardview. Could you show your xml file which contains the recycler view?

Comment: @csabapap.Thanks but i have already tried by removing cardview.even though its showing same

Comment: you should upload your xml file which contains the recycler view because the problem probably there.

Comment: @csabapap.updated question

Comment: android:elevation="0dp" in cardView

Comment: @JasonFang. i have fixed my problem you can see my question and answe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CardView layout\_width="match\_parent" does not match parent RecyclerView width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503760/cardview-layout-width-match-parent-does-not-match-parent-recyclerview-width)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have fixed my issue using following answer

The docs for `inflate`:

> Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource. Throws
>   InflateException if there is an error.
>
> Parameters resource ID for an XML layout resource to load (e.g.,
>   R.layout.main_page) root view to be the parent of the generated
>   hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that
>   provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned
>   hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.) attachToRoot Whether the
>   inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter? If false,
>   root is only used to create the correct subclass of LayoutParams for
>   the root view in the XML. Returns The root View of the inflated
>   hierarchy. If root was supplied and attachToRoot is true, this is
>   root; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file.

It is important here to not supply true, but do supply the parent:

```
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_listitem, parent, false);
```

Supplying the `parent` View lets the inflater know what layoutparams to use. Supplying the false parameter tells it to not attach it to the parent just yet. That is what the RecyclerView will do for you.

This answer helped me to fix my problem

Ref: [CardView layout_width="match_parent" does not match parent RecyclerView width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503760/cardview-layout-width-match-parent-does-not-match-parent-recyclerview-width)

Comment: Please supply both your java side code and your xml next time!

Comment: @NicholasChen. i already solved my problem.i have added answe

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it works with this change:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FilialCruzaViewHolder {
    // Before
    // val binding = ListaFilialCruzaCardItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)) 

    // After
    val binding = ListaFilialCruzaCardItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return FilialCruzaViewHolder(binding)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using layout_margin in CardView tag, remove them. This is how your code should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/primaryDarkColor"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="8dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:padding="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:text="content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ff212121"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: @Bhavesh.Thanks but i have already tried by removing cardview.even though its showing same

Comment: what about the rootView of layout where you have placed RecyclerView, have you checked there yet?

Answer (score 0):

all them layoutsz

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**
    android:background="#e5e5e5"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

From what you can see, you're wrapping content on the second linear layout, simply make changes there and all's good.

Be sure NOT to match parent recklessly for that horizontal linear layout, it might overflow!

Comment: @Nicholos.let me try.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The second LinearLayout's width is wrap_content. It should be match_parent. You should delete the second layout because it is useless. Set the first LinearLayout background to #e5e5e5

Answer (score 0):

try to use margin and padding to your cardview and remove all margin attributes. Hope it will work. And try to reduce using layouts.
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:padding="5dp"