# CardView width is not matching to width of the screen?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to match the CardView width to the screen width but CardView width is not matching to screen width. I have checked my code again and again and I've even made all the attributes width equal to match parent.

Recyclerview xml --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DisplayTodayExercises">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/exercises_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Card view xml --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_general_dimen"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exer_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        tools:text="Exercise Name"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/se_eps"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/sets_reps_dimen"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        tools:text="5 x 6"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/sets_reps_dimen"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Inflating code

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercises_card_view_layout, null);
    return new ExerciseContentViewHolder(view);
```

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyyER.png)

[image]

Comment: Is there any change if you switch `orientation` to `vertical` on the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: No, sir. Which LinearLayout by the way?

Comment: And how exactly do you inflate your Fragment/activity layout which contains RecyclerView?

Comment: Can you extend the code where you inflate your ViewHolder?

Comment: I've provided the code above.

Comment: please, could you provide your reclyer view initialization code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with your inflater. Check out the documentation for [LayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html), specifically for the inflate method.

Try this:

```
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.exercises_card_view_layout, parent, false);
```

Instead of supplying null, supply the parent view. This way the inflater knows what LayoutParameters to use. Supplying false parameter tells the LayoutInflater not to attach it to the parent just yet. The RecyclerView will handle this for you.

Comment: Always attach source of your code if it's not yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503760/cardview-layout-width-match-parent-does-not-match-parent-recyclerview-width?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: You are welcome.
@muminers - I have encountered such a problem and explained how I solved it. I copied the part of the code from my own application, just changed the name of the view. After all, it's a generic line of code that is always used in cases like this and it's highly likely and this was posted as answer several times. I cannot link to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of known issue. You can wrap your CardView with eg RelativeLayout or try the solution from here: [CardView layout_width="match_parent" does not match parent RecyclerView width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503760/cardview-layout-width-match-parent-does-not-match-parent-recyclerview-width?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)