# Cardview in Contraint Layout resizing not as supposed

Tags: android, android-cardview

I'm having trouble with this layout because is not working as I supposed. The textview inside the CardView is afecting the other views and the size of the card.

[image: App sample screenshot]

But when I see the xml, the other elements are not constrained to the size of the textview (or maybe I'm just stuck and I can't see it).

This is my xml. At design time, it works fine, but in runtime, the card width resizes. Any ideas?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#C6C6C6"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/company_logo"
    android:layout_width="68dp"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/aguas_cartagena"
    android:contentDescription="@string/company_logo"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/company_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/company_logo"
    android:text="XXX"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/company_logo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/company_logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pay_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/company_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/company_logo"
    android:text="Fecha pago: 14-Abr-2020"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/company_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/company_name" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon_status"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/company_name"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_online" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pay_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="$ 999.999.999"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/icon_status"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/company_name" />
 
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
 
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**EDIT:**
For who has the same problem, I've found a solution in this post (second accepted answer):
[Use RelativeLayout as the immediate parent to CardView.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503760/cardview-layout-width-match-parent-does-not-match-parent-recyclerview-width)

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I hope the second card should not be shrinked (It must be like the first card). Or at least the text should not be overlapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For who has the same problem, I've found a solution in this post (second accepted answer):
[Use RelativeLayout as the immediate parent to CardView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503760/cardview-layout-width-match-parent-does-not-match-parent-recyclerview-width)

The solution was to enclose the Cardview layout inside a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" ... >
    <CardView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" ... >
    </CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use thias xml code

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#C6C6C6"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/company_logo"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"
        android:contentDescription="company_logo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/company_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="XXX"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/company_logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/company_logo"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pay_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/company_logo"
        android:text="Fecha pago: 14-Abr-2020"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/company_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/company_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_status"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"


        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_online" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pay_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="$ 999.999.999"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/icon_status"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/company_name" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Used this code or use Linear Layout instead of constrainLayout

Answer (score 1):

**Use this Layout it Will never overlap well tested:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#C6C6C6"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/company_logo"
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"
                android:contentDescription="company_logo"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/company_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/icon_status"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/company_logo"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/company_logo" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pay_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/company_logo"
                android:text="Fecha pago: 14-Abr-2020"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pay_value"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/company_name"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/company_name" />

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_status"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"


                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_online" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pay_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="$ 999.999.999"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/icon_status"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/company_name" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```